# Topological Group, symmetric neighborhood, Hausdorff, disjoint open sets

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a topological group with identity $e$. If $A, B$ are subsets of $G$, we let $A * B$ denote the collection of elements $a * b$ for $a \in A, b \in B$, and we let $A^{-1}$ denote the set of elements $a^{-1}$ for $a \in A$.

a. A neighborhood $V$ of $e$ is said to be symmetric if $V^{-1} = V$. Show that if $W$ is any neighborhood of $e$, then there exists a symmetric neighborhood $V$ of $e$ such that $V * V \subset W$.

b. Suppose that $G$ is $T_1$ as a topological space. Show that then $G$ is necessarily Hausdorff. Specifically, if $x \neq y$ are given, show that there exists a neighborhood $V$ of the identity such that $V * x$ and $V * y$ are disjoint.

c. Show that if $G$ is $T_1$, it is in fact regular. Recall that a space $X$ is said to be regular if for all $x \in X$ and all closed subsets $A \subset X$ not containing $x$, there exist disjoint open sets $V, W$ such that $x \in V, A \subset W$.

Comment: Many users on this site appreciate knowing what your thoughts are on the question. So tell us, what have you done so far? where are you stuck?

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:**

**a**. For an arbitrary nbhood $W$ of $e$, let $U=W\cap W^{-1}$, then plainly $U=U^{-1}$, $U$ is a nbhood of $e$, and $U\subset W$. (now use,
theorem:
 Neighborhood Axioms of $e$).

**b**.
  If $G$  is a topologial group the following conditions are equivalent:

i) $G$  is a $T_0$   space.

ii) $G$  is a $T_1$   space.

iii) $G$
is a $T_2$
space.

iv) If $\beta_e$
is a fundamental system of neighborhoods of $e$
 then
$\bigcap
β e ={e}$.

v) $\{e\}$ is a closed subgroup of $G$.

**c**. Every topological group is regular.

I'll refer you to a few books on topological groups. Hopefully useful to you.

1. A. Arhangel'skii, M. Tkachenko, [Topological Groups and Related Structures](http://books.google.com/books?id=B785AETmFKEC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false).
2. T. Husain, [Introduction to topological groups](http://books.google.com/books/about/Introduction_to_topological_groups.html?id=x_7uAAAAMAAJ).
3. E. Hewitt, K. A. Ross, [Abstract Harmonic Analysis: Volume 1](http://books.google.com/books/about/Abstract_Harmonic_Analysis.html?id=uf11K1wXEYUC).